# How to solve Graph returned an error: Error validating verification code error in Facebook Login Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with Graph API on facebook and I want to log in and test app in the localhost.
I got the following error.

```
Graph returned an error: Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request
```

Comment: _“Does anybody work with graph API?”_ - that is not what you should ask here as the (current) “main point” of your question. Please go read [ask], if you have not done that yet.

Comment: Did you check on what the error message asked you to?